# ¿Que lenguaje de programación no inicia un arreglo en cero?

Tags: javascript, java, c#, python, c

Tengo la inquietud de que lenguaje de programación no inicia un arreglo en cero ?

Comment: ¿El contenido del arreglo en cero o el indice del arreglo a partir de cero?

Answer (score 6):

Un ejemplo es [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html), que emplea un arreglo en 1. Es habitual su uso en las ingenierías y resulta habitualmente confuso por dicho motivo.

*Edit*:
He buscado alguna cosa más y he localizado estas 2 tablas en Wikipedia que indican los arreglos para varios lenguajes. [Tabla 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(array)#Array_dimensions) [Tabla 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(array)#Array_system_cross-reference_list)

Lenguajes que inician con 1:

- ALGOL 68
- APL
- AWK
- CFML
- COBOL
- Fortran
- FoxPro
- Julia
- Lingo
- Lua
- Mathematica
- MATLAB
- PL/I
- RPG
- R
- Ring
- Sass
- Smalltalk
- Wolfram Language
- XPath/XQuery

Espero sea útil ;)